# addition function for input that comes within ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can someone please point me in the right direction or give me anything on how to make an addition function work with an input that will be created dynamically and is as long the ng-repeat ( which is mostly more than one ) ?  I am having trouble on connecting the input by ng-model with the function, so couldn't accomplish anything.

the simplest form of can be like this...

```
<div ng-repeat="gameName in gameNames track by $index">
    <p> {{gameName.title}}</>
    <input type="number" > 
</div>
```

Result : {{total}}

will be forever thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to add a ng-model in the input so angular can track it:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="gameName.value">
```

For a calculated field, add a method to your controller

```
$scope.total = function() { 
     var total = 0;
     angular.forEach($scope.gameNames, function(gameName, key) {
         total = total + gameName.value;
     });
```

and then bind to it directly. It will know when it needs to recalculate as its constituent values change.

Comment: thanks a lot. One more silly question tho, what exactly should I pass on the expression ???

Comment: you mean, to evaluate the total? Just call it as a function `<div>{{total()}}</div>`

Comment: Still wondering why can't I get the result with {{total()}} cos I can see the result when I console.log(total) inside of the function but not outside of the function

Comment: never mind, I've changed every total into $scope.total and called {{total}} then all is alright now